# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') using LinearRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am practicing machine learning in python. I am stuck on an obstacle but I am having difficulties. The data set I am using is titanic.csv. I am trying to calculate the Age column missing values using Linear Regression.

```
training = dftrain[['Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare','Pclass','Sex_female',
                'Sex_male','Embarked_C','Embarked_Q','Embarked_S']]
testing  = dftest[['Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare','Pclass','Sex_female',
               'Sex_male','Embarked_C','Embarked_Q','Embarked_S']]
unify = pd.concat([training, testing])
train = unify[unify['Age'].notnull()]
clf = LinearRegression()
#clf.fit(train.drop(['Age'],axis = 1), train['Age'])
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None )
train
```

I have manually tried to fix the error by doing,

```
train[train['Age'].isnull()]
```

using the above code I getting columns with no values indicating that there are no NaN values. I did this for all the columns. I also checked using,

```
train.notnull().count() 
Age           1046
SibSp         1046
Parch         1046
Fare          1046
Pclass        1046
Sex_female    1046
Sex_male      1046
Embarked_C    1046
Embarked_Q    1046
Embarked_S    1046
dtype: int64
```

but whenever I think everything is good to go and I uncomment the clf.fit() function I get the error

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Please help I can't figure out what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `train.notnull().count()` : This will return the total number of non-NaN values in each column. It won't return count of NaN values. You can also check this by comparing this number(1046 in this case) with total number of rows present in the dataset.

Use `train.isnull().sum()`to find total number of NaN values present in the training dataset. if you see positive number then you have NaN values in your trainset.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error because my data (in a couple of the columns) contained some non-numeric values. Once I did some datawrangling (replaced null values with the mean of that column), then it worked fine.

```
mean=df['bedrooms'].mean()
df['bedrooms'].replace(np.nan,mean, inplace=True)
```

then

```
features =["floors" ,"bedrooms" ,"sqft" ,"bathrooms"]     
X = df[features]
Y = df['price']
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X,Y)
lm.score(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to construct the training set from those rows of 'unify' that contain no NaN values:

```
train = unify.dropna()
```

Comment: Yes. I tried to do that. I shall explain it further. when after doing the train.isnull.sum() there was one value in Fare column with NaN, further, I wanted to see that row it turned out it had 2 rows with the same index one of them did not have null and the other had a null value in Fare. So I filled the NaN value with mean and later the two rows with the same index disappeared. somehow... but it worked so that's good I guess